# xterm is displaying raw escape sequences

Tags: centos, xterm

I currently have an old Red Hat Enterprise Linux server (release 6.7). From this server I’m able to open an xterm and telnet to an OpenVMS machine. Once connected to OpenVMS I can run LSE (the language sensitive editor) with no issues.

Now, I have a new CentOS server to replace the Red Hat server but when I connect to my OpenVMS machine, it appears as if xterm is just printing the escape characters rather than interpreting them correctly.

I am running xterm to emulate a VT100. The command is basically `xterm -xrm backarrowKeyIsErase -e telnet hostaddr`. Entering the sequences manually works as expected in a new xterm window and again after establishing the telnet connection. It’s LSE that doesn’t seem to work anymore.

For example, I'm seeing sequences similar to `]?K?21;H?;7m` being printed.

I’ve been trying to see if there are configuration difference between to old server and the new server but I haven’t found much. In both cases, the `TERM` environment variable is set to `xterm-256color` and the locales also seem to match.

I’ve managed to try this from a different CentOS machine and it works. So there must be some configuration or missing package on my new machine. I just need to find out what’s different.